# set up proxy with ANT

Tags: java, ant, proxy

Java version: 1.8.0
ant version: 1.7.1

I am trying to execute this ant to build jar file. This ant also does http connection to maven to download some jar files:

Since I am behind proxy, I do this first:

```
export ANT_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=prod.proxy.net -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.proxyUsername=smithJ -Dhttp.proxyPassword=Basketball123"
```

then I execute this:

```
CLASSPATH=/app/hbase-0.94.27/lib/hadoop-core-1.0.4.jar CFLAGS=-m64 CXXFLAGS=-m64 ant -v compile-native tar
```

I get these errors:

```
ivy-download:
      [get] Getting: http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.2.0/ivy-2.2.0.jar
      [get] To: /app/hadoop-lzo/ivy/ivy-2.2.0.jar
      [get] Error opening connection java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 407 for URL: http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.2.0/ivy-2.2.0.jar
      [get] Error opening connection java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 407 for URL: http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.2.0/ivy-2.2.0.jar
      [get] Error opening connection java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 407 for URL: http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.2.0/ivy-2.2.0.jar
      [get] Can't get http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.2.0/ivy-2.2.0.jar to /app/hadoop-lzo/ivy/ivy-2.2.0.jar
```

407 errors are proxy authentication errors. What am I doing wrong here? How would I authenticate in proxy to get http files?

I also tried this:

```
 CLASSPATH=/app/hbase-0.94.27/lib/hadoop-core-1.0.4.jar CFLAGS=-m64 CXXFLAGS=-m64 ant -Dhttp.proxyHost=prod.proxy.net -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.proxyUsername=smithJ -Dhttp.proxyPassword=Basketball123  compile-native tar
```

still 407 errors.

Answer (score 2):

Check this:

```
set ANT_OPTS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxyhost -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.proxyUser=myproxyusername -Dhttp.proxyPassword=myproxypassword -Dhttps.proxyHost=myproxyhost -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080
```

The guide is `"-Dhttp.proxyUser"` instead of in your case`"-Dhttp.proxyUsername=smithJ"`, that's why I always tell others copy instead of typing.

Guide here:http://ant.apache.org/ivy/faq.html

Comment: you are using this proxy for other applications?

Comment: yes, I can set up proxy in my shell to wget stuf from internet

Comment: if you are giving a wrong password, will the error code change?

Comment: I changed the password to something different, still 407 error code. I am issuing set ANT_OPTS in my current shell, right before the ant command. Do I need to insert set ANT_OPTS in any profile file like /etc/profile.d/java.sh?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113341/http-407-proxy-authentication-required-how-to-handle-in-java-code  I was just reading this answer, I think that's some problem with ANT or the HTTP lib ANT depends.

Comment: If it still doesn't work, maybe it's your dependency file which is not ok. Check if the module name you depend on is actually a name of directory under
www.ibiblio.org/maven/. If this is the case, check if the jar with a name like [module]-[revision].jar is present under the jars directory of this module on ibiblio. For instance: www.ibiblio.org/maven/commons-httpclient/jars/commons-httpclient-2.0.jar

Comment: Last comment was coping from http://ant.apache.org/ivy/faq.html, it suggests you checking the httpclient that ANT required. Let's try if the httpclient 2.0 solve that problem.

Comment: I do set APT_OPT=<all that mentioned above>, when I do echo APT_OPT, I only get back this: -Dhttp.proxyHost=prod.proxy.net

Comment: I exited out from shell, do another set ANT_OPTS and echo $ANT_OPTS does not show anything. Now I dont even get the errors, it just hangs.

Comment: Put "commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1" jar into your classpath, and try again.

Comment: the same error, ant is not able to connect to maven via http proxy.